# How to store pictures paths from res/drawables folder?

Tags: android, android-drawable

I need to do an Quiz App with pictures associated to the questions. 
The problem is that there should be default questions with the app and in future the app shall be able to create more questions and i dont know how to store  the pictures paths on database mainly because of the default questions.

My first aproach is to have the default pictures in the `res/drawables` but how can i get the path of `res/drawables` pictures?

I hope to have explained my problem well.

Comment: You can't have nested folders in drawables, so the path doesn't make sense. Try using assets folder instead

Answer (score 1):

Res/drawables doesn't have paths.  They have integer ids.  So there's no path to get.  Those ids also change every compile, so hardcoding them isn't always ideal.

I would suggest that the first time you start up, you write those default images to disk.  This gives you two benefits-  one you have a path.  Two, you can treat default images and non-default images with the exact same code.

Comment: Could you please tell me where i should put  the code to copy the images on the first time the app starts up?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on [Android Save and Retrieve Image Path From Database](http://valokafor.com/android-save-and-retrieve-image-path-from-database/)